# Getting the current script executing filename in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, include

Okay, I've been searching for this for way too long already... I'm trying to find out how I can return the filename of the page that's running an included javascript, from inside that javascript.

I can easily do this in PHP using `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']`, but in Javascript this seems to be a lot harder.

Do I really need to substring it from `location.href` or is there a more efficient way? Could jQuery help?

Comment: The `location.href` solution assumes that your filename is exposed in the URL.  It won't work if your URL are rewritten -- see this question's URL.

Comment: Hmmm, that IS an important note to keep into account - thanks Nikki. Do you happen to know an alternative solution to fix this problem? I'm using it in a jQuery AJAX function, so the PHP solution is no option here, I'm afraid.

Comment: There are some other possibilities to get to the filename, the question is - what are you trying to do, what are you needing the filename for?

Comment: It needed to be passed in an AJAX-call. The project in question is no longer relevant, but I am still curious how one might work this out with rewritten URL's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the Url Parameters

```
function getFileName()
{
  var url = window.location.pathname;
  var lastUri = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
  if(lastUri.indexOf('?')!= -1)
     return lastUri.substring(0,lastUri.indexOf('?'));
  else
     return lastUri;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var url=location.href;
return url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1)
```