# How to get current .php or .html file name by JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Can I get the current .php or .html file name by JavaScript? The script is in the external file in respect to current .php or .html, so need the name file name of this current .html of .php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    ...
    <script src="js/Script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196606/getting-the-current-script-executing-filename-in-javascript) but the variable value was empty, maybe because currently I use the local host. Anything that can to do which will be work on both local and remote host?

Comment: Depends on the way you are running the server. `window.location` may help but depends on your routing algo. for. eg if you run in this page you will actually not get php or html because the uri routing will not show it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the current script executing filename in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196606/getting-the-current-script-executing-filename-in-javascript)

Comment: Pls say why soln of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196606/getting-the-current-script-executing-filename-in-javascript doesnt work as it uses same `window.location.pathname` as ur accepted answer.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Really I used the ` var fileName = location.href.split("/").slice(-1);` solution because it is short. I could not delete this question myself and make the flag. Sorry again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Window Location](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp)

Verify if this document can help you.

It must be something, like this:

```
var page = window.location.href;
```

Comment: Only in a rudimentary implementation. If you use a templater engine or routing in php window.location will not see anything releavant. for example this page will give `/questions/38341122/how-to-get-current-php-or-html-file-name-by-javascript`. Not the html or servre filename

Comment: Yes, you're right, this code is good in case URL have the script name.

Comment: he has said http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2196606/getting-the-current-script-executing-filename-in-javascript doesnt work. how is that question different?

Comment: This post that you show me is an alternative for the problem of Gurebu

Answer (score 3):

Below is the simple code to get full URL and filename of URL:

Example1:

```
var url=location.href;
var urlFilename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
```

OUTPUT1:

```
url => http://localhost/demo/index.php
urlFilename => index.php
```

OUTPUT2:

```
url => http://localhost/demo/
urlFilename =>
```

urlFilename will be empty in case of url is rewritten to (http://localhost/demo/)

Example2: I do not know if you want to use php inside javascript, if you are desperate to get the filename this is one way to do it.

```
var filename = '<?= __FILE__?>';alert(filename);
//output: ex: /opt/lampp/htdocs/demo/index.php
var url2 = filename.substr(filename.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
//output: ex: index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Create following function to get the current .php or .html file's name in JavaScript.

```
const getCurrentFile = () => {
    let url = window.location.href;
    let objs = url.split("/");
    return (objs[objs.length-1]);
}
```

Here, with the help of JavaScript's split function, we splits the url with "/" and then returned the last element.